# Custom Button distorts in SPAN tag

Tags: html, css

I have to generate custom buttons in a row.  The problem is when I place the button class inside of a "span" tag, the button shape turns from round to oval.  If I place it inside of a "div" tag, it displays fine, but not in a row.

Here is my CSS:

```
.dashboard-button-green{
    height: 27px;
    width: 27px;
    background-color: #72a017;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
   top:10px;
   padding-top: 12px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 2px;
   color:white;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="ContractorCtrl">


            <span class="dashboard-button-green">70%</span> <span><img src="~/Images/ContractorWidget/red_cross.png" /></span>





       </div>
```

This is how it renders:

[image]

The image on the left should look like the image on the right.  I tried changing the line-height, but it didn't help.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the span tag is inline. You need to add `display: inline-block` to your span to behave more like a button.

Comment: Thanks!  This was EXACTLY what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your css:

```
span{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is EXACTLY what I needed!

Comment: block elements expand to available space and no test follows them. If you want a button you should use `inline-block`. That is the style that browsers use for buttons by default. Also you shouldn't style all span tags like the code mentioned in the answer. This will change the behavior of all span tags.